# Obtaining JSON feed from XAMPP localhost on Eclipse

Tags: php, android, json, eclipse

I'm quite new to android and programming and I am attempting to write an app that would download a JSON feed from the internet and display it on the screen.

I don't have access to a server so I'm using XAMPP. From my research, would I have to write the following code in PHP so that it will echo the JSON to my app?

```
<?php
echo "{"array":[1,2,3],"boolean":true,"null":null,"number":123,"object":{"a":"b","c":"d","e":"f"},"string":"Hello World"}"
?>
```

Then in Eclipse, would I have to make the url of the app point to "localhost"? Therefore, in the tutorial http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html
would I say:

```
URL url = new URL(http://locahost);
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### 1. Set up your backend(in your case PHP)

first make a project folder inside your htdocs.(depends where you installed xampp).

1. make a folder named with your project.
    for examle `API`
   so you will have `C:\xampp\htdocs\API`
2. next create `index.php` file inside that project so then you will have this file:
   `C:\xampp\htdocs\API\index.php`
3. put your PHP code into that index.php
4. test your back-end by accessing `http://locahost/API/index.php`; it should show you a json encoded string.

### 2. Change your API call:

```
URL url = new URL(http://locahost/API/index.php);
```

Comment: Thank you. Just a small correction to the above, in point 2 change your api call, the line to put into android code is: URL url = new URL (http://10.2.2.2/API/index.php); instead of localhost. Localhost doesn't seem to be recognised in android code.